# Why does GraphQL query work with the "query" keyword before the curly braces?

Tags: asp.net-core, graphql

I created a small API for authors and books as example. The problem is that I don't understand why a query can look different but still get me the same output. I've included 3 examples.

The GraphQL query looks like this:

```
{ 
 "query":
  "query{
  author(id: 1) {
    name
  }
 }"
}
```

Why is this query working if within the query is the keyword "query" two times? When I write the query like this:

```
{ 
 "query":
  "{
  author(id: 1) {
    name
  }
 }"
}
```

it also works, and when I write it like that:

```
{ 
 "query":
  "author{
  author(id: 1) {
    name
  }
 }"
}
```

It is not working. Why is that so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GraphQL specifies three types of [operations](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Language.Operations):

> - query – a read‐only fetch.
> - mutation – a write followed by a fetch.
> - subscription – a long‐lived request that fetches data in response to source events.

What you are sending to your server is a JSON object with a single property (`query`) the value of which is a GraphQL [document](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Language.Document) that represents your actual request to the GraphQL service. This property is (unfortunately) called `query` by convention **but it has nothing to do with the actual operation inside the document you are sending**.

Any operation included in your GraphQL document must follow this format:

```
OperationType [Name] [VariableDefinitions] [Directives] SelectionSet
```

`Name`, `VariableDefinitions` and `Directives` are all optional. The `OperationType` is one of `query`, `mutation` or `subscription`. `SelectionSet` is the collection of fields you are requesting for that operation type. **Only selection sets are wrapped in curly brackets.** In your example, you have two selection sets -- one containing the `author` field and one containing the `name` field.

There's an exception to the above called **query shorthand**:

> If a document contains only one query operation, and that query defines no variables and contains no directives, that operation may be represented in a short‐hand form which omits the query keyword and query name.

In other words if your operation:

- is a query
- is the only operation in the document
- contains no variable definitions or directives

You can omit the `query` keyword and the operation name. This leaves you with just a selection set, which is wrapped in a set of curly brackets.

So your first two examples are equally valid. The third example is not valid because `author` is not a valid operation kind.

Answer (score 1):

The first `query` key on your examples is a requirement from GraphQL to actually call the endpoint, it has to be present to actually run `queries` **or** `mutations`. You can see it in the [docs](https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/#post-request).

The first example works because at the root of a GraphQL Schema there has to be an action with keywords `query` or `mutation`, and in your case you are triggering a `query`.

The second example works because if you don't define what type of action (`query` or `mutation`) on your request, it always defaults to execute a query.

The third example does not work because you don't have the action `author` at the root of your Schema.

*I guess the first keyword `query` is what makes some confusion in this case.*